# How to fix " Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally" in node js app built using pkg?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using whatsapp-web.js in my personal express api project to send messages. Everything is working fine when I run the project from vscode. When I build the app using pkg, it says `Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run`npm install `to download the correct Chromium revision (982053)`.

I tried providing chrome installation path in executablePath property.
`const launchOptions = {executablePath: 'path/to/chrome'}; const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ launchOptions });` 
It is still the same. I want the app to use the installed Google Chrome in the system.

My node version is 18.16.0 and puppeteer version is 20.5.0.